# Receive SMS not working (java android)

Tags: java, android, sms, broadcast

I do not understand, when I receive an sms nothing appears.

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public MyReceiver() {
    }

    private static final String RECEIVE_MSG = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if(intent.getAction().equals(RECEIVE_MSG)){
            Bundle extra = intent.getExtras();
            if(extra!= null){
                Object[] pdus = (Object[])extra.get("pdus");
                final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                for(int i = 0; i<pdus.length; i++){
                    messages[i]= SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                }
                if (messages.length>-1) {
                    for (int i = 0; i<messages.length; i++) {
                        final String messageBody = messages[i].getMessageBody();
                        final String phoneNumber = messages[i].getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                        Toast.makeText(context,"Expéditeur:" + phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Toast.makeText(context,"Message : " + messageBody, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This is not nearly enough information to diagnose your problem.

Comment: DO you have the recieve sms permission?  And if you're on KitKat or higher read http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html.

Comment: Yes I am android 6 , I add permissions but it is true I can not add run time permissions for sms received , but where should I mettres ? Thanks

Comment: "I can not add run time permissions for sms received" - Why not, exactly? The user will have to launch an `Activity` to bring your app out of the _stopped_ state anyway; do it then.

Comment: I am a beginner , could you be more specific thanks

Comment: I pick the incoming sms , get the content , if GPS coordinates display on the map that I have already created ..

Answer (score 0):

Are you registered the reicever in manifest or Activity?

```
<receiver android:name=".broadcast.SmsBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="5000">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
        </intent-filter>

</receiver>
```

or

```
 IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
 filter.setPriority(9999);
 registerReceiver(new SmsBroadcastReceiver(),filter);
```